# jQuery change each element with class when it comes into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of blocks that repeat like this:

```
<div class="producto_banner">
    <div class="positioner">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="titulo">Title</div>
            <div class="subtitulo">Subtitle</div>
            <div class="introduccion">Intro</div>
            <a class="boton" href="#">anchor</a>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img src="image source">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="producto_banner">
    <div class="positioner">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="titulo">Title</div>
            <div class="subtitulo">Subtitle</div>
            <div class="introduccion">Intro</div>
            <a class="boton" href="#">anchor</a>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img src="image source">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

And I would like to animate the `.right` div inside each of them when they come into view.

So far I have this:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var centerY = Math.max(0,((jQuery(window).height()-
jQuery(elem).outerHeight()) / 2) 
              + jQuery(window).scrollTop());

    var elementTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(elem).height();

    return elementTop <= centerY && elementBottom >= centerY;
}

$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
    console.log('scrolling');
    $(".producto_banner").each(function(index, element) {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(element)) {
            $(this).find('.right').animate({'right':'50px'},1000);
        }
   });
});
```

But for some reason it’s only animating the last 2 blocks (out of 5)

Comment: Can you include the CSS as well please, I'd like to see the dimensions of everything and how they are positioned.

Comment: Seems to works for me: http://output.jsbin.com/sujapad except the last because it's not fit to the condition..

Comment: @zer00ne it goes something like this https://jsfiddle.net/24qdhs2b/1/

Comment: @MoshFeu funny... this is in my enviroment http://montenegrostudio.com/bium/casa

Comment: Found the problem. All these itmes are inside a div that has a margin top 100% which is causing problems with the isScrolledIntoView function. When the first `producto_banner` comes into view it triggers the third which is one screen size below, when the secon `producto_banner` comes into view it triggers the fourth, again, one screen size below, etc.